# SQL Server Table Join - Is it Possible to Iterate Through Potential Matches and Ignore Previously Matched Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a migrated dataset of orders where on migration some of the original products were merged into the same "new product." In the example below Product 1 and 3 were merged into a "New product 1."

When the orders were migrated over, rather than combining product 1 and 3 on an order they were loaded as separate line items just with the same product name. I need to join these two tables and get a 1-1 relationship for the order line items.

My issue is that when I join on (Table2.Legacy_Order_number = Table1.Order_number and Table2.Amount = Table1.Amount) my results include duplication since there are 2 possible matches.

My question is: Since it does not matter which of the two "New Product 1" line items from Table 2 is matched back to Product1 and Product3 from Table 1, Is there a way to iterate through the potential matches and then ignore already matched records?

Current Query:

```
SELECT
     T1.ID AS Original_Order_Number
    ,T1.Name AS Original_Product
    ,T2.ID AS New_ID
    ,T2.Name AS New_Product
    ,T2.Amount
FROM Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T2.Legacy_Order_number = T1.Order_number 
        AND T2.Amount = T1.Amount
```

Table 1:

| Order Number | Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product1 | 50.00 |
| 1 | Product2 | 100.00 |
| 1 | Product3 | 50.00 |

Table 2:

| ID | Legacy Order Number | Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 1 | New Product 1 | 50.00 |
| 20 | 1 | New Product 2 | 100.00 |
| 21 | 1 | New Product 1 | 50.00 |

Desired Query Result :

| Original Order Number | Original Product | New ID | New Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product1 | 19 | New Product 1 | 50.00 |
| 1 | Product3 | 21 | New Product 1 | 50.00 |
| 1 | Product2 | 20 | New Product 2 | 100.00 |

Comment: If you want to iterate in an RDBMS you are almost certainly doing what you want wrong. Perhaps what you want it a correlated subquey in the `FROM` by using `APPLY` and limiting the results from said subquery with a `TOP` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I am not familiar with using APPLY, so not sure how I would go about that. But I will try to look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can add a partitioned row-number to each table, then add the row-numbers as a join condition**

This means that each row is only joined once to a matching row, while still keeping `Order_number` and `Amount` as the main joining condition.

```sql
SELECT
     T1.ID AS Original_Order_Number
    ,T1.Name AS Original_Product
    ,T2.ID AS New_ID
    ,T2.Name AS New_Product
    ,T2.Amount
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Order_number, Amount ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM Table1
) T1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Legacy_Order_number, Amount ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM Table2
) T2
    ON T2.Legacy_Order_number = T1.Order_number 
        AND T2.Amount = T1.Amount
        AND T2.rn = T1.rn;
```